# Will enabling authorize.net test mode in magento admin on one website affect another one using the same account but not in test mode?

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Since I saw that authorize.net has a global account setting for test mode, I want to know if there is any risk with enabling test mode on an authorize.net account through magento admin to   other magento websites using the same account but not in test mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Authorize.net's API a test mod ise available at the request level using the variable x_test_request.

Looking at magento/app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Model/Directpost/Request.php function setConstantData() you can see that setXTestRequest is called if the test setting is enabled.

If you enable this you won't impact other connections [on different stores], if you the global option from Authorize.net's side clearly it will be global. Either way when dealing with payments you should always test after any change to insure you don't mistakenly lose sales [or charge yourself].

Source: http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/Test_Transactions/Test_Transactions.htm